# CUDA wrapper for Qt

Tags: c++, qt, cuda, opencl

Qt have released a nice wrapper for Opencl ( [QtOpencl](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/opencl-snapshot/) ) which does a very good job of hiding a lot of boiler plate and making OpenCL play nicely with Qt's display widget and Opengl.

But there are a few things that I can do better in Cuda than OpenCL and the Cuda tools are much more mature.

It's relatively easy to make a simple Cuda C++ wrapper and integrate into the Qt build process but I wondered if anybody had done anything more? Ideally an equivalent **QtCuda** library.

The Qt people aren't interested in Cuda support because it's not cross platform enough

edit: Just for search, there is a [Qt CUDA](http://11235813tdd.blogspot.com/2011/10/mandelbrot-qt-and-cuda-with-opengl.html) wrapper for openGL PBO. It's based on the Dr Dobbs [simplePBO example](http://drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/222600097). There are a couple of bugs fixes needed to make it play nicely with Cuda4 but it's a good start.

ps there is no way to contact the author of the blog and comments don't work - if he finds this let me know and i will send the fixes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The Qt people aren't interested in Cuda support because it's not cross platform enough

Exactly. If you want to ignore this, you don't understand Qt's philosophy. And why create even more legacy-code, while it's easy to translate your existing kernels to OpenCL with [MultiscaleLab Swan](http://www.multiscalelab.org/swan)?

But the source of the library is free to download and used as a base.

Comment: Depends on your defn of legacy! With cuda my app will run in a CCTV camera using a Tegra chipset. With OpenCL I'm stuck running on "legacy" CPUs on PCs. I need this to be Cuda because some people have ported some very complex libs to Cuda, it's less work to wrap Cuda for my app than implement and prove all that maths on OpenCL. By having it all wrapped in Qt I can use either Cuda or OpenCL much more easily.

Comment: This would be a good point, if it were true; The official list http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_gpus.html does not speak of Tegra at all. Also a CCTV with Qt would be quite strange, since its strong focus on GUI-development. The CUDA-libs you are referring to are not ported to ARM; the open-source libs are mostly ported to OpenCL. Ported code has the same math, since CUDA and OpenCL are a sort of incompatible dialects.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make myself clear. Two reasons for going Cuda, one is that embedded NVidia chipsets (like Tegra) with Cuda are replacing custom DSPs in a lot of embedded apps (especially machine vision) the other is lots of existing image processing and maths code in Cuda.  The Qt was for the desktop prototyping, having Qt do all the OpencL/GPU specific boilerplating and would let me switch between them in the prototype stage easily.

Comment: So Tegra drivers support CUDA, but not OpenCL? That seems pretty strange. Maybe you should ask Nvidia for OpenCL capable drivers.

Comment: @dietr - we are working with NVidia, their view is that Cuda performance will always be better than openCL because they can tweak the implementation for their HW (and of course they want you to choose a soln that locks you in)

Comment: Sure, Nvidia wants to make sure that OpenCL remains a second-class citizen, but IMO you shouldn't let me do this. There's no real reason for why OpenCL performs worse than CUDA.

Answer (score 3):

The way I did it was to build a DLL in Visual Studio, warped CUDA Function call among normal C exported functions. They used `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` from QT IDE. All in all, it worked quite well.